# match and subtract chronologically

Tags: r

Sample Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Customer.ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
5L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A123", "B561", "C985", "D456", "Z893"
), class = "factor"), Month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), Score = c(12, 
16, 8, 20, 16, 15, 6, 22), Increase = c(12, 16, 8, 20, 4, 16, 
-2, 2)), .Names = c("Customer.ID", "Month", "Score", "Increase"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

Customer.ID Month Score Increase
     A123     1    12       12
     B561     1    16       16
     C985     1     8        8
     D456     1    20       20
     A123     2    16        4
     Z893     2    15       16
     C985     2     6       -2
     D456     2    22        2
```

What I need to do is get the value in column "Increase".  So essentially,match first column by their ID, and then chronologically by "Month" take the difference in the "Score" column to get the "Increase" value.  If there is no match, keep the value. 
How do I accomplish this using any R package necessary?

Comment: can you please provide some reproducible code, what you have done, and the desired output

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use use `dplyr` package. First group data on `Customer.ID` and then `arrange` it on `Customer.ID` and `Month`. Now, all you have to perform is to subtract the previous value from the current `Score`. Since, OP has  mentioned that if no match found then same `Score` should be shown in `Increase` column hence use `lag` with `default=0`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Customer.ID) %>%
  arrange(Customer.ID, Month) %>%
  mutate(NewIncrease = Score - lag(Score, default = 0))

# # A tibble: 8 x 5
# # Groups: Customer.ID [5]
#   Customer.ID Month Score Increase NewIncrease
#   <chr>       <int> <int>    <int>       <int>
# 1 A123            1    12       12          12
# 2 A123            2    16        4           4
# 3 B561            1    16       16          16
# 4 C985            1     8        8           8
# 5 C985            2     6      - 2         - 2
# 6 D456            1    20       20          20
# 7 D456            2    22        2           2
# 8 Z893            2    15       15          15
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Customer.ID | Month| Score| Increase
A123| 1| 12| 12
B561| 1| 16| 16
C985| 1| 8| 8
D456| 1| 20| 20
A123| 2| 16| 4
Z893| 2| 15| 15
C985| 2| 6| -2
D456| 2| 22| 2",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, sep = "|")
```